# dynmacially generating href tags with jinja2 under flask

Tags: python, flask, jinja2

I referred to [jinja2](http://wsgiarea.pocoo.org/jinja/docs/loops.html) for loop documentation but no luck generating following html dynamically.

```
     <li>
        <a href="#1"> This is the first sentence</a>
     </li>
     <li>
        <a href="#2">This is the senond sentence</a>
     </li>
     <li>
          <a href="#3">This is the third sentence</a>
     </li>
     <li>
          <a href="#4">This is the fourth sentence</a>
     </li>
```

Something like this should work:

```
{% for i in length %}
  <li>
     <a href="#{{i}}"> This is a sentence </a>
  </li>
```

where length changes every-time and is already predefined by a python script at background!
here length = 4.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you are trying to do is iterate on non iterable object ie. on integer.

```
{% for i in range(1, length+1) %}
    <li>
        <a href="#{{ i }}">This is sentence {{ i }}.</a>
    </li>
{% endfor %}
```

This will work.

Answer (score 1):

```
{% for i in range(1, length+1) %}
<li>
 <a href="#{{i}}"> This is a sentence </a>
</li>
```

should work